# C++, OpenCV, & Kinect: Processing speed goes down

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

I use C++ (Visual Studio 2015) and OpenCV (ver 3.2.0) to process data sent from Kinect v1. My C++ program has no problem when it starts debugging for the first time. After it stops debugging and re-start debugging, however, it gets very slow.

I am suspecting that the program closes without releasing some memory (i.e., memory leak). I am aware of that I would need to use the `delete` function to release the memory if I use the `new` function. But I didn't use the `new` function in the C++ program (I neither used the `malloc()` function, which is equivalent to the `new` function in C programs).

For OpenCV, I use the `destroyAllWindows` function at the end of the program. For Kinect v1, I also use the `NuiShutdown()`, `Release()`, and `CloseHandle()` functions at the end of the program.

Is there anything else I need do to release the memory (e.g., releasing memory associated with `Mat` in OpenCV)? Or is something else causing the decrease in processing speed?

I'd appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: `new` and `delete` are not functions. These are operators. See: [new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and [delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After first run disconnect **Kinect** then reconnect and try second run.

If all goes well now then the problem is most likely stuck thread. The device access is usually handled by separate threads and especially with **USB** they can get stuck (in case of error or sync problem between accessing form host and expecting on device side) until you disconnect device (not sure which **Kinect** driver are you using but **JUNGO** version which `NuiShutdown()` infers have this problem). You can also check task manager before disconnection if there are not some stuck processes left after first run.

To remedy this you need to find out what are you doing wrong during access. It could be:

1. **wrong USB port**

   use the back side not front slots.
2. **invalid USB transfer request**

   device is always waiting for specific set of commands or stream and waits until it does not receive it so it blocks all other things. So using unsupported commands or reading in wrong times or sizes of packets can cause this.
3. **USB communication is out of sync**

   PC host can timeout in case you do not have enough **CPU** power while critical operation is processed (or have opened too many apps on background).

   This can be caused also by wrong gfx driver as I suspect you are using rendering ... **Intel HD graphics** can generate such problems with ease especially on notebooks. Try to disable any rendering in your app or at least limit rendering to **OpenGL 1.0** to see if speed is the same in between runs. If this is the case the whole desktop usually flickers or is not repainting parts of apps ... and animations are sometimes sluggish.

   Another problem might be a debugger. If without it all is well then debugger is the problem and you can not solve it. Debugging while accessing **IO** can cause sync and timeout problems especially with **USB**.

To check for memory leaks you can simply see how much free memory you got before 1st run and compare it to values after 1st,2nd,3th .. runs if the value lowers you got something stuck somewhere. After app close all the memory belonging to app is freed by **OS** so even if you forget some `delete` that does not matter unless some thread is still running ...

Some **USB** drivers based on **libUSB** I encountered got also problem with Handle leaks. But that behaves differently ... all runs fine until there are no free handles. After that **OS** is non functional you can not open any window,app, anything ... until any app is closed.

**[Edit1] Front USB slots**

Front slots are usually connected to motherboard with relatively long cable (usually flat and not very well shielded) so it is more susceptible to noise. Also as it is located usually around **HDD** and above high frequency parts of the motherboard it also induce it into the **USB** feed. All this degrades the quality of **USB** signal causing much much bigger rejection rate hence lowering sync capability and also the overall usable bandwidth.

If you compare that with backside **USB** ports they have no cables but are connected directly in **PCB** with short and well shielded paths so the connection quality is much much better.

So if you use device demanding high bandwith or synchronism then front ports are a bad choice.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying to my inquiry so quickly! I will test my program using the methods you described.

Comment: Spektre: I tested following your instructions. My program no longer slows down after changing the USB port from the front slot to back slot. Would you please tell me why it was wrong to use the front slot? Thank you very much.